# Rockscout and Vanilla music

Tags: applications

On my Galaxy S5 Android 6.0.1 I've installed Rockscout and Vanilla music to play music with my mirrorlink car infotainment. If I run Vanilla Music, it reads all files on the internal memory and the external microsd, but inside Rockscout, it "sees" only audio files on the internal memory.
How can I play all music with with Vanilla inside Rockscout?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved myself: you have to select the target directory to add to the media library, TAP on that directory and THEN click "save".  Selecting only the directory and click "Save" is not sufficient (no action is done).